# Restarting rownumber based on conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

I am running one query and getting following results

```
Select *
from 
(Select ROW_NUMBER() over 
    (partition by [HOSP_CODE],[MRN] 
    order by [HOSP_CODE],MRN,ADM_DATETIME ) as rownumber,* 
from Live.tempnewbornbundling) as a
order by [HOSP_CODE],MRN,ADM_DATETIME
```

DATA

```
Rownumber key     MRn    hospcode adm_date         sep_date         Sequence
--------- ------- ------ -------- ---------------- ---------------- --------
1         7099222 544607 3        22/07/2011 04:55 22/07/2011 10:44 First
2         7099223 544607 3        22/07/2011 10:45 25/07/2011 19:43 Middle
3         7099224 544607 3        25/07/2011 19:44 26/07/2011 11:29 Middle
4         7099225 544607 3        27/07/2011 12:30 27/07/2011 19:30 First
5         7099226 544607 3        27/07/2011 19:31 28/07/2011 19:31 Final
1         7099227 559282 3        03/07/2011 22:50 03/07/2011 23:51 First
2         7099228 559282 3        03/07/2011 23:52 04/07/2011 15:30 Middle
3         7099229 559282 3        04/07/2011 15:31 04/07/2011 17:59 Final
4         7099230 559282 3        05/07/2011 18:00 05/07/2011 18:05 First
5         7099231 559282 3        05/07/2011 18:06 09/07/2011 14:58 Final
```

How can I further make partitions and assign row numbers based on sequence values, 
for example I want to restart rownumber each time there is first in same group HOSPcode, MRN

```
Rownumber key     MRn    hospcode adm_date         sep_date         Sequence New rownumber
--------- ------- ------ -------- ---------------- ---------------- -------- -------------
1         7099222 544607 3        22/07/2011 04:55 22/07/2011 10:44 First    1
2         7099223 544607 3        22/07/2011 10:45 25/07/2011 19:43 Middle   2
3         7099224 544607 3        25/07/2011 19:44 26/07/2011 11:29 Middle   3
4         7099225 544607 3        27/07/2011 12:30 27/07/2011 19:30 First    1
5         7099226 544607 3        27/07/2011 19:31 28/07/2011 19:31 Final    2
1         7099227 559282 3        03/07/2011 22:50 03/07/2011 23:51 First    1
2         7099228 559282 3        03/07/2011 23:52 04/07/2011 15:30 Middle   2
3         7099229 559282 3        04/07/2011 15:31 04/07/2011 17:59 Final    3
4         7099230 559282 3        05/07/2011 18:00 05/07/2011 18:05 First    1
5         7099231 559282 3        05/07/2011 18:06 09/07/2011 14:58 Final    2
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please remember that appreciation on SO is recognized with upvotes and accepted answers. I would highly suggest perusing the [FAQ] for more basic info about the site, especially the [FAQ#HowToAsk] How to Ask

Comment: When you're `PARTITION`ing by `[HOSP_CODE],[MRN]`, then all rows within the same partition will have the same values in those columns - so why have you included them in the `ORDER BY` also?

Comment: All those `First`, `Middle`, `Final` values don't seem to make much sense, it would likely be enough to have just a `RestartsTheSequence bit` column: `1` = the sequence is restarted, `0` - the sequence is continued.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with a [recursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx)

You will want to do the recursion on the rownumber (that will make sure you end), and then just keep incrementing a new rownumber column everytime you recurse, resetting when you hit first.  I believe the below answer should work. I would store the previous query in a temp table

```
WITH FinalValues (RowNumber, Key, MRN, HospCode, adm_date, sep_date, 
    sequence, NewRowNum)
AS
(
-- Anchor member definition
SELECT RowNumber, Key, MRN, HospCode, adm_date, sep_date, 
    sequence, 1 AS NewRowNum
FROM PreviousQuery
WHERE RowNumber = 1
UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition
SELECT P.RowNumber, P.Key, P.MRN, P.HospCode, P.adm_date, P.sep_date, 
    P.sequence, 
    CASE WHEN P.sequence = 'First' THEN 1 ELSE NewRowNum + 1 END AS NewRowNum
FROM PreviousQuery AS P
INNER JOIN FinalValues 
    ON FinalValues.RowNumber = P.RowNumber + 1
)
-- Statement that executes the CTE
SELECT *
FROM FinalValues;
GO
```